# ROS & PCL on ARM A9

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, pcl, embedded, cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build a system with ROS and PCL on XILINX ZYNQ ZC702 SoC.
I would like to know if any one has build it for an ARM Cortex A9 system.

I am finding it difficult to cross compile with the cross compiler provided from Code Sourcery. Any tips or guidance will be helpful.

Thanks,
Anup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50285/ros-&-pcl-on-arm-a9/) by [anupkini](https://answers.ros.org/users/3772/anupkini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-12-12

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-12-12**:
I'm still unsuccessful in my attempts, (and am getting less and less time to experiment) but perhaps an answer to [my question on stack_overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844772/how-to-cross-compile-cmake-for-arm-with-cmake) might help you out a little.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-12**:
Since you have no tags, it is likely that no one who knows about this will see your question.

**Comment by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on 2013-01-31**:
Hi,
I have not tried cross compiling on ARM myself, but is there anyway you could directly compile ROS on your target? I have had success on this for A8 and A9 chips

Aswin

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-01-31**:
I took the freedom and added few tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using this a guide before giving up :(
[link](ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/sourceforge/c/project/ca/carm/ROS%20cross-compile%20on%20ARM.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1